# Save lookup value to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I've figured out how to add a record into a library. The only thing I am trying to figure out is how (or maybe where) do I save a user's selection from a lookup list?

In the below code snippet, I am saving a new list item. It saves without error, but the fields "AwardType" and "AwardReason" are lookup fields and, although I do not get an error, nothing gets saved to them. How do I save to a lookup field selection from a user?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = (new FileInfo(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)).OpenRead())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["Awards"];
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.Add("wfRecipientName", txtRecipientName.Text);
            ht.Add("Office", txtOrganization.Value);
            ht.Add("AwardType", ddAwardTypes.SelectedValue);
            ht.Add("AwardReason", ddAwardReasons.SelectedValue);

            SPFile destfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUpload.FileName, fs, ht, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a lookup's value is done with SPFieldLookupValue(ID, Value).

You need to store the object returned by this method in a list item field, not a property via a hash table. In my example below, Awards list is document library and AwardType is a field of type lookup.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Awards"];
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("Office", "Chicago"); // standard property
SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName), fs, ht, true);
SPListItem item = file.Item; // get the item for the just-added file.

// assign the lookup column using SPFieldLookupValue
item["AwardType"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(
    Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue),
            DropDownList1.Text);
item.Update();  // to save the lookup column.
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly,  the line

```
SPListItem item = file.Item; // get the item for the just-added file.
```

is key.

I had trouble when I used the code below - the lookup did not update consistently!?

```
file.Item["AwardType"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(
    Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue),
            DropDownList1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the SPFieldLookUpValue as string to the HashTable, not the value of the Lookup.
Properties stored on HashTable other than int, string, date will not be parsed on Document creation.

```
    SPFieldLookupValue v = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["lookUpField"].ToString());
Hashtable documentProperties = new Hashtable();
documentProperties.Add("key", v.ToString());
 SPFile file = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add("fileName", memoryStream, documentProperties, true);
```

The same can be done with complex objects as SPUser.

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, web.CurrentUser.ID, web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
  documentProperties.Add("SPuSER", userValue.ToString());
```